# Azure Authentication for Xamarin Forms - Conflicting Recipes/Guides

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to add authentication to my Xamarin Forms app and using azure mobile apps .

However i'm getting conflicting guides about how to proceed from Xamarin & Microsoft websites .

Xamarin : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/azure/

Microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#client-facebook

Which one is more current/recommended ?

I want to add Facebook authentication + my own custom one .
[i have not found any proper guides how to create a custom login/register system with azure mobile apps]

Answer (score 0):

Answered (including the specific one around Facebook) in my book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - this book is current recommendation.

Comment: To answer your specific question as well, The learn.microsoft.com version is current advice for Azure Mobile Apps.